# I'm using Eclipse with JavaCard. How to make a reset and send the APDU to the reader

Tags: javacard

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen with JavaCard classic kit 3.0 installed.
How to make a cold reset (get ATR) from the script and send the GetDate APDU to the card inserted into the reader. I need several examples of Java code (it's not Applet) and how the reader is accessed and how the emulator is accessed. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing a java card applet, then I recommend using JCIDE against a standard eclipse package.

If you are developing an off-card application to access java card, then following set of API's will be helpful. They are pretty straight forward to use.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/

1. Use class "TerminalFactory" to get list of terminals available.
2. Use class "Card" to connect to a card.

.. other operations

Make sure: -

1) Driver for reader is installed and reader is working while connected to PC.

Comment: Thank you! You sent me in the right direction. That's just not understand how to handle the output, for example ATR =[B@4F3F5B24

Comment: The ATR would be a byte array, parse it as standard Hex data. It provides the information about the card.

Answer (score 0):

My choice is Smart Card Scripting Environment for Eclipse (SSE4E).
While everything works!
If anyone is interested - https://www.openscdp.org/sse4e/index.html